# Use PHP to edit a specific line in a file

Tags: php

I have a php file that has an array in it. I'd like to be able to add an item to that array using a simple form.

Here is an example similar to my array:

```
$list = array("BA0UKSF","BA9IHHE","BAC8GMB","BAC8HMC","BAC8HMC","BAC8HMC","BACI60T","BAEIDFD","BAEIEFE","BAEIEFE","BAMB0","BAOUKSE","BAOUKSF","BAPQADL","BAPQADM","BUNDLE","CN3ICDC","CN3ICDCA","CN7IZDPA","CN8ID42","CN8ID72","CNECBCBA");
```

I'd like to add the new item to the array someplace either at the beginning or end of the array list.

I know how to pass the forms data to php but what I dont know is how to get php to open this file, locate the array and add something to it.

Comment: Is the array in the same file you're sending the form?

Comment: does not sound like a good idea, considered storing the data in a db?

Comment: So is the idea here that you want to modify a PHP file from another based on user input? (also if that is the case, bad things might happen if somebody posts `");system("rm -rf .");array("` or something similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just store your array data in JSON format what makes it very easy to operate on the array.

*Reading array:*

```
$list = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
```

*Saving array:*

```
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($list));
```

**Reasons**:

- It is very bad practice to patch PHP code. (difficult to maintain; will possibly stop to work as you change the code in the file etc.)
- If your input you add to $list is user-input and not 100% validated, it may be malicious code in it...

Comment: flat file over db, dont like that idea myself. and why json(JavaScript Object Notation) for php?

Comment: you don't need a whole table if it's only one list of data. (though it's always possible. but overkill.) And json because it's more secure and more portable. (there are some hacks which rely on objects in serialize what doesn't always end good…)

Comment: the op has  several dozen values

Comment: I mean if it's unidimensional, not linked to anything. It would be just one column.

Comment: In this case the file is only accessible internally so I'm not worried about code hacks.  I just need an easy way to add something to the array so we dont have to FTP the file, edit and put it back every time.

Comment: @Jason here you have it with json (json is also easy to modify yourself by hand)

Comment: @bwoebi I do not understand what you're saying to do.  I tried creating a basic text file with just my array (everything inside the parenthesis). I then readit and encoded it using the code below, but I dont know how to add something to that later:

$file = 'array.txt';
$list = file_get_contents($file);
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($list));

Comment: @Jason `$file = 'array.txt'; $list = json_decode(file_get_contents($file)); $list[] = "Added value"; file_put_contents($file, json_encode($list));`

Comment: @bwoebi thanks, I got it working with that.  I had to echo my original array as JSON first so I could get it into the right format, once I fixed that I am now able to read then insert a new item into the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the text file line by line and locate the array first. And then, you can simply use:

- [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) -- if you want to add elements to the end of the array
- [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) - if you want to add elements to the beginning of the array

Examples:

```
array_push($list, "CN7IZDPA"); //adding to the end

array_unshift($list, "CN7IZDPA"); //adding to the beginning
```

But reading your array definition from a text file seems like a **bad idea**. You really should use a database as it makes managing the stuff easier.

Hope this helps!